# jQuery adding a class to multiple list with same class

Tags: jquery, addclass

I have multiple list with the same class name for a menu, and for some reason, when I click on one of them, it doesn't change for all the menus. Am I missing something?

Here is the JS, sorry for the long irrelevant codes:

```
/***** START SLIDER ****/
$(function() {
/*  
number of fieldsets 
*/      
var fieldsetCount = $('#formElem').children().length;               
/*  
current position of fieldset / navigation-form link     
*/      
var current     = 1;                
/*  
sum and save the widths of each one of the fieldsets        
set the final sum as the total width of the steps element   
*/
var stepsWidth  = 0;        
var widths      = new Array();      
$('#steps .step').each(function(i){         
var $step       = $(this);          
widths[i]       = stepsWidth;           
stepsWidth      += $step.width();       });     
$('#steps').width(stepsWidth);              
/*      
to avoid problems in IE, focus the first input of the form  
*/      
$('#formElem').children(':first').find(':input:first').focus();
/*      
show the navigation-form bar    
*/      
$('.navigation-form').show();               
/*  
when clicking on a navigation-form link         
the form slides to the corresponding fieldset   
*/      
$('.navigation-form a').bind('click',function(e){           
var $this   = $(this);          
var prev    = current;          
$this.closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');         
$this.parent().addClass('selected');
var sameClass = $this.parent().attr('class');
$('.'+sameClass).find('li').removeClass('selected');
sameClass.replace('selected','');
$('.'+sameClass).parents('li').addClass('selected');
/*      
we store the position of the link           
in the current variable         
*/          
current = $this.parent().index() + 1;           
/*      
animate / slide to the next or to the corresponding         
fieldset. The order of the links in the navigation-form         
is the order of the fieldsets.          
Also, after sliding, we trigger the focus on the first      
input element of the new fieldset           
If we clicked on the last link (confirmation), then we validate         
all the fieldsets, otherwise we validate the previous one           
before the form slided      
*/          
$('#steps').stop().animate({            
marginLeft: + ((widths[current-1]+127*current-127)*-1) + 'px'       
},500,function(){   
if(current == fieldsetCount)            
validateSteps();        
else                
validateStep(prev);         
$('#formElem').children(':nth-child('+ parseInt(current) +')').find(':input:first').focus();    
});     
e.preventDefault(); 
});         
/*  
clicking on the tab (on the last input of each fieldset), makes the form    
slide to the next step      */  
$('#formElem > fieldset').each(function(){  
var $fieldset = $(this);        
$fieldset.children(':last').find(':input').keydown(function(e){         
if (e.which == 9){              
$('.navigation-form li:nth-child(' + (parseInt(current)+1) + ') a').click();    
/* force the blur for validation */                 $(this).blur();     
e.preventDefault();     
}   
});
});     

});

/***** END  SLIDER ****/
```

and the file for the html

```
<div id="dialog" class="dialog"></div>
    <div id="content-form">
        <div id="wrapper-form">
        <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

            ....

            ?>
            <div id="steps">
                <form>
                    <fieldset class="step">
                    <div class="para">
                    You have successfully submitted the form
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>


        <?php } else { ?>
            <div id="navigation-form" style="display:none;" class="navigation-form">
                <ul>
                    <li class="selected step1">
                        <a href="#">Start</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="step2">
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="step3">
                        <a id="step3a" href="#">Equipment</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="step4">
                        <a href="#">Confirm</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>


            </div>
            <div id="steps">
                <form id="formElem" name="formElem" action="http://170.75.154.211/~atozmovi/moving-cost-calculator/" method="post">

                    <fieldset class="step">
                        <legend>Start</legend>
                        <div class="para">
                            <label for="service-type">Type of Service</label>
                            <select name="service-type" id="service-type">
                                <option value="" disabled selected value="select">Select Service</option>
                                <option value="full">Full Service</option>
                                <option value="labor">Labor Only</option>
                                <option value="junk">Junk Removal</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="para">
                            <label for="num-movers">Number of Movers</label>
                            <select name="num-movers" id="num-movers" disabled>
                                <option value="select" disabled selected>Select Service</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both;height:20px;"></div>
                <div class="estimated">
                <span class="price" id="price">Estimated Price: Need More Information</span>
                <br /><span class="estimated-time" id="estimated-time">Estimated Time: Need More Information</span>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        <div id="navigation-form" class="navigation-form next-button">

                <ul>
                    <li style="display:none;">
                        <a href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="step2">
                        <a href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
                </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="step">
                        <legend>Services</legend>
                        <div class="para" id="truck">
                            <label for="truck-size">Truck Size</label>
                            <select name="truck-size" id="truck-size">
                                <option value="select" disabled selected>Select Truck Size</option>
                                <option value="10">10'</option>
                                <option value="14">14'</option>
                                <option value="17">17'</option>
                                <option value="20">20'</option>
                                <option value="26">26'</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="para" id="hours">
                            <label for="num-hours">Number of Hours (Minimum 2)</label>
                            <select name="num-hours" id="num-hours">
                                <option value="select" disabled selected>Select Estimated Hours</option>
                                <option value="2">2 Hours</option>
                                <option value="3">3 Hours</option>
                                <option value="4">4 Hours</option>
                                <option value="5">5 Hours</option>
                                <option value="6">6 Hours</option>
                                <option value="call">Call For Other Hours</option>
                            </select>
                         </div>
                        <div class="para">
                        <label for="services">Services</label>
                        <div class="multi-checkboxes">
                            <div class="tall-check"><input id="loading" name="services" type="checkbox" value="loading" /></div> Loading and Unloading
                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            <div class="tall-check"><input id="driving" name="services" type="checkbox" value="driving" /></div> Driving
                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            <div class="tall-check"><input id="packing" name="services" type="checkbox" value="packing" /></div> Packing
                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            <div class="tall-check"><input id="cleaning" name="services" type="checkbox" value="cleaning" /></div> Move-in / Move-out Cleaning
                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                            <div class="tall-check"><input id="help" name="services" type="checkbox" value="help" /></div> General Helper
                            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div style="clear:both;height:20px;"></div>
                <div class="estimated">
                <span class="price" id="price">Estimated Price: Need More Information</span>
                <br /><span class="estimated-time" id="estimated-time">Estimated Time: Need More Information</span>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                <div id="navigation-form" class="navigation-form next-button">
                <ul>
                    <li style="display:none;">
                        <a href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="display:none;">
                        <a href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="step3">
                        <a href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="step">
                        <legend>Equipment</legend>
                        <div class="para">
                            <label class="label-header" >Boxes</label>
                            <label for="large">Large</label>
                            <input id="large" name="large" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" />
                        <br />
                            <label for="medium">Medium</label>
                            <input id="medium" name="medium" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" />
                        <br />
                            <label for="small">Small</label>
                            <input id="small" name="small" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="para">
                            <label class="label-header" >Wardrobe Boxes</label>
                            <label for="sm-wardrobe">Shorty</label>
                            <input id="sm-wardrobe" name="sm-wardrobe" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" />
                            <br />
                            <label for="lg-wardrobe">Grand</label>
                            <input id="lg-wardrobe" name="lg-wardrobe" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="para">
                            <label class="label-header" >Mirror / Picture Boxes</label>
                            <label for="sm-mirror">Small</label>
                            <input id="sm-mirror" name="sm-mirror" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" />
                        <br />
                            <label for="lg-mirror">Large</label>
                            <input id="lg-mirror" name="lg-mirror" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" /><br />
                            <label for="pic-ship">Picture Shipper</label>
                            <input id="pic-ship" name="pic-ship" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="para">
                            <label class="label-header" >Extras</label>
                            <label for="tape">Tape</label>
                            <input id="tape" name="tape" type="number" placeholder="Quantity" />
                            <br />
                            <label for="dolly">Dolly</label>
                            <select name="dolly" disabled>
                                <option selected>Included</option>
                            </select><br />
                            <label for="blanket">Blanket</label>
                            <select name="blanket" id="blanket">
                                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                <option value="no">No</option>
                            </select><br />
                            <label for="junk">Junk Removal</label>
                            <select name="junk" id="junk">
                                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                                <option value="no" selected >No</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both;height:20px;"></div>
                <div class="estimated">
                <span class="price" id="price">Estimated Price: Need More Information</span>
                <br /><span class="estimated-time" id="estimated-time">Estimated Time: Need More Information</span>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                 <div id="navigation-form" class="navigation-form next-button">
                <ul>
                    <li style="display:none;">
                        <a href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="display:none;">
                        <a href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>
                    <li style="display:none;>
                        <a href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="step4">
                        <a href="#">Next</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="step">
                        <legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>
                            <div class="para">
                            <label class="label-header">Contact Information</label>
                            <label for="cust-name">Name</label>
                            <input id="cust-name" name="cust=name" type="text" placeholder="Name" /><br />
                            <label for="cust-phone">Phone Number</label>
                            <input id="cust-phone" name="cust-phone" type="text" placeholder="Contact Number" />
                            <br />
                            <label for="address">Address</label>
                            <input id="address" name="address" type="text" placeholder="Address" />
                            <br />
                            <label for="city">City</label>
                            <input id="city" name="city" type="text" placeholder="City" />
                            <br />
                            <label for="state">State</label>
                            <input id="state" name="state" type="text" placeholder="State" />
                            <br />
                            <label for="zip">Zip</label>
                             <input id="zip" name="zip" type="text" placeholder="Zip" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="para">
                            <label class="label-header">Terms and Conditions</label>
                            <div style="width:100%;float:left;clear:both;text-align:left;">
                            <p>Terms and conditions as follows: </p>
                            <p>...
</p>

                        </div>
                          </div>
                         <div class="para">

                        </div>
                        <div style="clear:both;height:20px;"></div>
                < div class="estimated">
                <span class="price" id="price">Estimated Price: Need More Information</span>
                <br /><span class="estimated-time" id="estimated-time">Estimated Time: Need More Information</span>
                 </div>
                 <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                         <div style="padding-top:20px;clear:both;">
                        <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" />
                        </div>
                         <div style="clear:both;"></div>

                     </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="step" style="width:10000px;background:none;">
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="side-atoz-widget">This is a side custom widget
        </div>
    </div>
```

the form is a modification of the code:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/07/fancy-sliding-form-with-jquery/

Thank you

Comment: I'd really like to help, but all I can see is http://jsbin.com/jutaji/1/edit It's not clear enough  why all those `display:none`, the "next"s and how it should actually perform. Are you sure that you explained it all in two lines of text? (Create a small example to help us picture what you're trying to do and improve your question with additional details. What's not working what you expect from your code etc etc)

Comment: http://170.75.154.211/~atozmovi/moving-cost-calculator/

Here is the link to the site. I hope it helps.
I'm trying to make the top menu bar sync with the next button, so when the next button is hit, the 2nd link gets highlighted.
It works fine when i click the top navigation...

Comment: Always check the console for errors. You have `validateStep is not defined` error. I think it is the result for your problem.

Comment: validateStep shouldn't affect it I don't think...

Answer (score 0):

I found it, thank you everyone who looked at my code
I just created alerts with variables and found that some of the objects were undefined. So i saw that the class was already the list

```
$('.'+sameClass).parents('li').addClass('selected');
```

this looked at the parent, although the class was already a list. I changed it to

```
$('.'+sameClass).addClass('selected');
```

works like a charm!